# Why can I not see the images from the Container Registry?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I have created a docker image and uplaoded it to Container Registry.

But when I try to access the image by clicking "Create a Deployment" from my K8s cluster, I get the following error: `You don't have permission to list images for this project`.

[image]

I was looking at [this](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles) doc and added the following roles: `Storage Admin` and `Storage Object Viewer`. Apart from that, I also have the role of an `Owner` assigned to me.

Can I please seek your guidance on what is it that I am missing here.

Comment: Update:  I was able to deploy the image to the cluster from the Container Registry page.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it via enabling the Artifact Registry API. (No need to migrate your existing Container Registry, simply to enable the Artifact Registry API)

I think it is related to the latest Google's [recommendation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr) to transitioning to Artifact Registry